# How to align numbers with \sim in tabularray in LaTeX?

Tags: align, tabularray

I need to align numbers as `99.88%~9.8%` in tables in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,amsmath,tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c,si={table-format=2.2\%}]}}
1&{{{$11.11\%\sim55.56\%$}}}\\
2&{{{$5.12\%\sim21.2\%$}}}\\
3&{{{$6.78\%\sim2.1\%$}}}\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Is there a way to align them with `si={table-format=2.2%\sim2.2%}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting them in `{{{` … `}}}` would disable the effect of the `siunitx` library, so I don't you want to do that.

I would just put the two sides of `\sim` in their own columns, and use the `@{}` operator to put the `\sim` between the columns. This precludes using `X` as the colspec, unfortnately, however, as this makes the columns too wide, but it's not clear why you would want that much space for them anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[c] S[table-format=2.2\%]@{\ $\sim$\ }S[table-format=2.2\%] }}
1&11.11\% &55.56\%\\
2&5.12\% &21.2\%\\
3&6.78\% &2.1\%\\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tblr aligned at \sim]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. May you teach me how to set `\sim` symbol's color to `{RGB}{245,246,246}`?

Comment: In this particular case you could do `@{\textcolor[RGB]{245,246,246}{\ $\sim$\ }}`, but that's far too light on a white background and almost unreadable. You've asked a number of questions on this site and not answered any. Time to start trying to answer simple questions like that for yourself.

Comment: Okay. I am writing my thesis. I will read several books about latex within two months and then I will answer questions here. I test these codes in `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/648880/settblrinnertblrcells-bg-cant-change-the-background-color-in-tabularr`, but there is an error. I can't adjust the table's color to `{RGB}{245,246,246}`.

Comment: You've also been here long enough to know "there is an error" is a useless thing to say. Anyway, discuss that issue is that topic, not here.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot!