# \SetTblrInner[tblr]{cells={bg= can't change the @{} background color in tabularray in LaTeX

Tags: tabularray

I set tables' background to `{RGB}{245,246,246}` in `tabularray` package, but the content from `@{}` in the table below didn't change to that colour, so it is still the original white. So is there a way to make that color change with `tabularray` package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\definecolor{tablebackground}{RGB}{245,246,246}
\SetTblrInner[talltblr]{cells={bg=tablebackground}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}{colspec={X[c] X[c,si={table-format=2.2\%}]@{\ $\sim$\ }S[table-format=2.2\%] }}
1&11.11\% &55.56\%\\
2&5.12\% &21.2\%\\
3&6.78\% &2.1\%\\
4&75.5\%&\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting `cells={bg=tablebackground}` only set background colors for all cells. But column specifier `@` will put its content `\ $\sim$\`  in the border. You may try to write

```
@{\colorbox{tablebackground}{\ $\sim$\ }}
```

but it won't work since the background color desen't fill the whole height. And it will cause an error which is an expansion bug of `tabularray`.

Therefore you may try to `\llap` and `\clap` the border text to zero width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\definecolor{tablebackground}{RGB}{245,246,246}
\SetTblrInner[talltblr]{cells={bg=tablebackground}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{talltblr}{
  X[c] X[c,si={table-format=2.2\%}] @{\llap{$\sim$\ }} S[table-format=2.2\%]
}
  1 & 11.11\% &  55.56\% \\
  2 &  5.12\% &  21.2 \% \\
  3 &  6.78\% &   2.1 \% \\
  4 & 75.5 \% &          \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[!htp]
\begin{talltblr}{
  X[c] S[table-format=2.2\%] !{\clap{$\sim$}} S[table-format=2.2\%]
}
  1 & 11.11\% &  55.56\% \\
  2 &  5.12\% &  21.2 \% \\
  3 &  6.78\% &   2.1 \% \\
  4 & 75.5 \% &          \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, if change `\begin{talltblr}{
  X[c] X[c,si={table-format=2.2\%}]
           @{\llap{\ $\sim$\ }}
           S[table-format=2.2\%]
}` to `\begin{talltblr}{
  X[c] S[table-format=2.2\%]
           @{\llap{\ $\sim$\ }}
           S[table-format=2.2\%]
}`. It is weird. Is there another way to change backgroud color of `@{}`?

Comment: @Y.zeng See my updated answer.

Comment: Hello. What's the function of  `\clap` in `!{\clap{$\sim$}}` and why did you add a `!` here?

Comment: @Y.zeng `\llap`, `\clap` and `\rlap` are three overlap boxes, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83930 .

Comment: @Y.zeng For the difference between `@` and `!` specifiers in tables, see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this problem is using `vline{} = {}{text=$\sim$}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,xcolor}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\definecolor{tablebackground}{RGB}{245,246,246}
\SetTblrInner[talltblr]{cells={bg=tablebackground}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{talltblr}{colspec={X[c,1.5] X[r,si={table-format=2.2\%},0.2] X[l,si={table-format=2.2\%},0.2]},vline{3} = {1-4}{text=\clap{$\sim$}}}
1&11.11\% &55.56\%\\
2&5.12\% &21.2\%\\
3&6.78\% &2.1\%\\
4&75.5\%&\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

But I don't know how to adjust table width to `\textwidth` and why `@{}` color is not the same as the table's.
[image]